# How to Select from a List based on another List?

Tags: list-manipulation

I could do this with Append[], If[], and a Do[] loop, but I'm sure there's a more elegant "Mathematica-like" way.

Example:
Selected the elements of b where the corresponding element of a is >3.

```
a={1,5,3,4};
b={w,x,y,z};
```

Desired result:

```
(* {x,z} *)
```

Comment: @m_goldberg  You are correct.  But I got several better Answers here than that Question did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4};
b = {w, x, y, z};
Pick[b, # > 3 & /@ a]
```

> `{x, z}`

Answer (score 8):

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4};
b = {w, x, y, z};

Pick[b, Sign[a - 3], 1]
```

> {x, z}

Or build an `Association` (if the keys are unique)

```
as = AssociationThread[a -> b];

Values @ KeySelect[as, # > 3 &]
```

> {x, z}

Comment: @JerryGuern. You should wait longer than that. Maybe as long 48 hours to see if don't get additional interesting answers. In the short term you should simply up-vote this answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways. Here is a pattern based solution.

```
Extract[b, Position[a, v_ /; v > 3]]
(* {x, z} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4};
b = {w, x, y, z};

Pick[b, Thread[Greater[a, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to show a few other methods

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4};
b = {w, x, y, z};

Cases[Transpose[{b, a}], {s_, n_ /; n > 3} :> s]

(*  {x, z}  *)

Inner[If[#1 > 3, #2] &, a, b, List] /. Null :> Sequence[]

(*  {x, z}  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Slight variation on the Pick pattern.

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4};
b = {w, x, y, z};
Pick[b, a, p_ /; p > 3]
```

> {x, z}

Answer (score 6):

This is very similar to danny's solution, but uses the new `GreaterThan` operator form with `Map`.

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4}; b = {w, x, y, z};
Pick[b, GreaterThan[3] /@ a]

(* {x, z}  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Two variations, using `Cases` and `Select`. `Cases` makes more sense here.

```
Cases[Transpose@{a, b}, {a_ /; a > 3, b_} :> b]
Select[Transpose@{a, b}, #[[1]] > 3 &][[All, 2]]
```